# iOS App name selection validity

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store-connect

When in the app submission process will one know if an app-name is available?

I created an app with a certain name and it's now ready for upload.
Does this mean the name is available/mine or will I only be certain once it passes review?

Comment: google for the name of iphone application that you want to use, if it exist then change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless it conflicts with some application that sounds very much like it *and* is popular, it would have told you the moment you created the application on Connect.